# Can't understand Gradle settings file,please add the path 'aar_file_name' manually error in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, aar, platform-specific

I want to add **.AAR** file into my flutter project. **How to add .AAR file ??** please help

I follow this steps in my **android studio** but it not work

> File --> New --> New module -->  import JAR/AAR package

it give this error

> Can't understand Gradle settings file,please add the path
> 'aar_file_name' manually error in flutter

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open the andriod Module
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXwLs.png)

Then import aar file in the andriod module.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. In my case, it was missing `settings.gradle` file. Make sure that the file exists at your project root. If not, just create an empty file and try again. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my project `open android module in android studio` was disabled due to lost of `xxx_android.iml`  file in android directory After
adding `xxx_android.iml` file I could able to add my `xxx.aar`  file in to project
[image]